# One to many merge based on a condition in two dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two large dataframes in pandas, for example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'start' : [5, 10, 15, 20], 'stop' : [10, 20, 30, 40]})   
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[6, 7, 8, 12, 13, 17, 19, 38, 39, 40]})
```

I want to merge them in a way that I append `start` and `stop` to the third dataframe if `id` is in `range(start, stop)` like so:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[6, 7, 8, 12, 13, 17, 19, 25, 38, 39, 40], 'start':[5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 30, 30, 30], 'stop':[10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 40, 40, 40]})
```

I tried this:

```
df3['start'] = pd.Series([0 for i in range(0, len(df2['id']))])
df3['stop'] = pd.Series([0 for i in range(0, len(df2['id']))])
for i in range(0, len(df2['id'])):
    if df['start'][i] < df1['id'][i] < df['stop'][i]:
        df['start'][i] = df3['start'][i]
        df['stop'][i] = df3['stop'][i]
```

But that gave me a error. Can someone please point out where I am going wrong and how to get the required dataframe? Also, is it always required to initialize a new variable with `pd.Series` like I have done above? Thanks!

Comment: Value 17 fits into two raings (10-20) and (15,30), you want just one record?

Comment: Yes, I want it to be in the lower (start, stop) range

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `df2` is sorted, you can use `searchsorted`

```
df2.join(df.iloc[df.stop.searchsorted(df2.id)].set_index(df2.index))

    id  start  stop
0    6      5    10
1    7      5    10
2    8      5    10
3   12     10    20
4   13     10    20
5   17     10    20
6   19     10    20
7   25     15    30
8   38     20    40
9   39     20    40
10  40     20    40
```

---

Or we can reference the underlying numpy arrays and perform the same logic

```
stop = df.stop.values
ids = df2.id.values
v = df.values

pd.DataFrame(
    np.column_stack([
        ids, v[stop.searchsorted(ids)]
    ]),
    columns=['id', 'start', 'stop']
)

    id  start  stop
0    6      5    10
1    7      5    10
2    8      5    10
3   12     10    20
4   13     10    20
5   17     10    20
6   19     10    20
7   25     15    30
8   38     20    40
9   39     20    40
10  40     20    40
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! what if `df` had many more columns and I only wanted to append `start` and `stop` from it to `df3`. Also could this join be done with a for loop like I tried?